# Dynamic for loops over lists (C#)

Tags: c#, for-loop, cartesian-product

I have 3 lists, containing strings

```
  GenderList = ["M", "F"] 
  AgeList    = ["10-15", "16-20", "21-26"]
  CityList   = ["CityA", "CityB"]
```

I want to make cross product over the lists, but danamically:
if the user asks for `gender_city`:
I need the following:

```
 foreach(var g in GenderList)
    foreach(var c in CityList
     .....
```

If the user asks for `gender_city_age`, the loop must be:

```
foreach(var g in GenderList)
  foreach(var c in CityList)
    foreach(var a in AgeList)
       ....
```

if the user asks for `city_age`

```
foreach(var c in CityList)
   foreach(var a in AgeList)
      ...
```

How can I make this? I have about `20` lists, I need to multiply lists' items *dynamically*
thanks

Comment: What do you want to do, concat-strings, build an object with all properties,...?

Comment: I am curious if there may be a better approach than using a bunch of for loops. I am not exactly sure what kind of data you are after, but this sounds like something that Sql Server or some sort of RDBMS may be more suited for what you are after as you can have conditional LEFT JOINs that may get you what you are after.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 table from database(gender, city, age) and I fill them into lists. I want to give the user  a count about (gender in city), (gender by age), (gender by city and age) I mean , I want the user fill an excel sheet containing dynamic col: gender    city coutn   or gender city age count  , or city age count ....etc

Comment: is your data linked by a foreign keys in your database tables?

Comment: No, separate tables, I want to generate excel dynamically

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a lot of questions; try doing a search for "Cartesian product", or see https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Answer (score 4):

Let's start from generalized `Cartesian`:

```
private static IEnumerable<T[]> Cartesian<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) {
  T[][] lists = source
    .Select(line => line.ToArray())
    .ToArray();

  if (source.Any(line => !line.Any()))
    yield break;

  int[] indexes = new int[lists.Length];

  do {
    yield return lists.Select((line, index) => line[indexes[index]]).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; ++i)
      if (++indexes[i] < lists[i].Length) 
        break;
      else
        indexes[i] = 0;
  }
  while (!indexes.All(index => index == 0));
}
```

Then we can try using it. Let's organize all the collections we want to query into a single *dictionary*:

```
// we allow to use any IEnumerable<string>, not necessary List<string>
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data = 
  new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "Gender", new [] { "M", "F" } },
    { "Age",    new List<string> { "10-15", "16-20", "21-26" } },
    { "City",   new [] { "CityA", "CityB" } },
};
```

And query it:

```
 string userChoice = "gender_city_age";

 var result = Cartesian(userChoice.Split('_').Select(name => data[name]));

 // Have a look at the result:
 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
   .Select(line => string.Join(", ", line)));

 Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
M, CityA, 10-15
F, CityA, 10-15
M, CityB, 10-15
F, CityB, 10-15
M, CityA, 16-20
F, CityA, 16-20
M, CityB, 16-20
F, CityB, 16-20
M, CityA, 21-26
F, CityA, 21-26
M, CityB, 21-26
F, CityB, 21-26
```

Comment: I will try, seems great answer, thank you very much